# How can I add just horizontal gridlines in a ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, visualization, gridlines

[image: Image Link here]

I want code to add just the horizontal gridlines.
I also cant see max values clearly when viewing, is there a way to add extra margin on the side.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. `theme_void()` makes the gridlines disappear (along with the majority of plot items). However, we can manually edit the `theme()` if we place the function after `theme_void()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,hp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_void() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_line(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_line())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>